# Repository vs. relational database

Tags: repository, relational-database

Most document repositories have version control built-in and some nice features like that.  If you are storing relational data (objects related on one another), however, some repositories don't enforce referential integrity.  There is discussion about repositories storing data as XML, which allows you to export the data if the software became unsupported.  I don't understand that argument, though.  You can store your data however you want in relational database, and export your data however you want, right?  If you wanted to migrate from MySQL to Postgres, that should be possible.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Repsotitory vs. relational database is kinda misleading, in terms of data might be unsupported is true, lets say they change data structure of the internals of what ever sql server you are running, then a old backup might not work, if enough years have passed and the backups havnt been converted to the new structure. .xml can be read by the human eye, since its plain text, and therefor the data is more likely to be store indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks Henrik.  You can use a XML database in that case, right?  Then you should be able to get the data as XML?

Comment: dunno if there is a XML database as such, but there is lots of tool that is easy to read and write xml files, however if there was such a think i would never use it in case there is user data, since it cannot be secured since you can just open and read the file. You would use .xml files to archive data however and i know you can use MS Sql to export tables to .xml files, i dunno if you can do it will all db managers, but it is quite simple to do, pretty much all coding languages has some packages that can help write or read xml.